# Is this ring a Dedekind domain?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a monic, irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. 
For the field $K:=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$, its ring of algebraic integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is always a Dedekind domain trivially.

Since the ring $R:=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p(x))$ is a subring of $\mathcal{O}_K$ (and sometimes they are even identical), I am curious about properties of $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p(x))$.

**For instance, is $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p(x))$ a Dedekind domain as well?**

Clearly, $R$ is an integral domain, and is noetherian, too. But I am unable to prove/refute (1), $R$ is integrally closed, and (2) every nonzero prime ideal of $R$ is maximal.

Can we prove that $R$ is an integral domain? Or can we impose some **strong**  restrictions on $p(x)$ such that the resultant $R$ must be a Dedekind domain?

Thanks!!

Comment: If $R$ is not the ring of integers, then it is contained in the ring of integers. Since the ring of integers is the integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $K$, this means that $ R$ is not integrally closed.

Comment: As said before me, this ring is not always integrally closed.  I just want to remark that not any ring of integers can be constructed that way because the ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ is not always of the form $Z[\alpha]$ ("most" of the times it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Mathmo123's comment above, did you consider any examples, e.g. $p(x) = x^2 + 3$?

Incidentally, you should be able to prove that any non-zero prime ideal is maximal.